# How to pass a variable to $scope in $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to pass a variable to $scope in $routeProvider. Code is following:

```
.when('/:zone/edit/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'views/edit.html',
      controller: 'EditSet'
    })
    .when('/articles/edit/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'views/edit-article.html',
      controller: 'EditSet',
      params: {zone: 'articles'}
    })
```

To get param I use `$scope.params.zone`, which works in first case (:zone) and does not work in second case.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think you might be better off using the function support in `templateUrl` to achieve this:

```
.when('/:zone/edit/:id', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        if (params.zone == "article") {
            return 'views/edit-article.html';
        }

        return 'views/edit.html';   
    },
   controller: 'EditSet'
})
```

Answer (score 4):

In the **order** you've specified, the second route will never be resolved.

`/:zone/edit/:id` will match any value for `:zone`. So `/articles/edit/:id` will always resolve to `/:zone/edit/:id`, as will `/foo/edit/:id` or `/asdhjkdajksa/edit/:id`.

Futhermore, `params: {zone: 'articles'}` is not a valid property of a route.  If you need data to be set before entering the controller you can use the `resolve` property (though I'm not sure that's what you need in this case).

```
.when('/articles/edit/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'views/edit-article.html',
  resolve: { zone: 'articles-zone' },
  controller: 'EditSet'
})
.when('/:zone/edit/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'views/edit.html',
  controller: 'EditSet'
})
```

I don't know how `$scope.params.zone` was working for you, it should be `$routeParams.zone` after you inject `$routeParams` into your controller definition.  Using the above routes and this controller you would get the following values:

```
angular.module('app').controller('EditSet', function($scope, $routeParams, zone) {
  console.log($routeParams.zone);
  console.log(zone);
});

/articles/edit/1
-> 'articles'
-> 'articles-zone'

/batman/edit/1
-> 'batman'
-> undefined
```

Have a look at [the example docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route#example) to see how to properly format routes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But `resolve` did not work for me, it causes an error. I changed order as you pointed, so now it works.